# What might cause a dog's carpal pad to turn pink and discharge fluids?

Tags: dogs, injury, skin-condition

I've noticed today that the "heel" of my chocolate lab's left front leg has some part of it not in its right dark color, with the fur around it looking a bit wet and sticky due to some discharge.

It's not really a part a dog steps on, so I'm not sure if he's likely to have hurt it somehow during a walk. I'm not sure it's swollen much, but anyway it seems to be on the pad itself so it's probably not part of the lighter skin that was pushed into visibility due to inflammation of sorts.

My dog is almost 6 years old and I want to make sure this isn't somehow a tumor of sorts. Thanks in advance.[image: photograph]

Comment: If you have worries about the health of your pet, please do not wait for the guesses of strangers from the internet. Only a vet can answer your questions definitely. Your question seems to talk about a part of the paw, but in the picture I can not see a paw. Maybe you can clearify this in some way?

Comment: @Allerleirauh I'm referring to the uppermost pad on the dog's front legs, which is apparently called the carpal pad. And it's weekend over here so I sent the vet a picture asking if he recognizes what it is. He said it looks like some kind of skin tumor but that it needs to be checked in person, but that wouldn't be until Sunday.

Comment: +1 for sending the vet a picture, this is importent context, because such questions would be closed, if no one knows, that the vet is already involved

Comment: @Allerleirauh I only sent it after having already asked here. But that doesn't mean a crowd of dog owners couldn't provide a good input after probably at least some of them have dealt with a similar looking condition.

Comment: But this is not, how this site works :) guessing is not well seen here. If you would read the guidlines, then you will see, that specify/name various illnesses is not in the scope of this site. If you know the illness (->vet), and ask "what can I do against xy" then we can help :)

Comment: @Allerleirauh Well, the vet saw him today and didn't give a specific diagnosis, but said it looks like some kind of inflammation rather than a tumor and gave him a topical medicine of sorts. We'll have to see if it improves by next week.